# Filter or delete row if cell is empty

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking to have a way to check cells on a specific column to see if it's empty. If it's in fact empty, filter or delete the row.

I tried to use code from similar questions to no success, as there seem to be multiple ways of doing it.

What I understand so far is I need to define the usual values:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Ordering"); // The particular sheet I'm using
var rows = ss.getDataRange(); // I assume this counts the rows?
var columntocheck = ss.getRange(1, 7, rows); // This defines the column I want to check for empty cells
var values = rows.getValues(); // Define value of the row to be checked?
```

This is where I'm not sure how to approach the next step. I see most people use for loop to check each row for data length or for "" or "0".

Would appreciate any tips.

Comment: The `getDataRange()` method counts both the rows and columns and it returns a range, not a number.  Use [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getLastRow()) to get a number that is the last row.  The `getLastRow()` method works from the sheet class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If sheet format (colors, fonts etc) is not important you can use this fast and efficient approach (it will clear the whole sheet and re-populate with data that has non empty cell in the column you have chosen) :

```
function deleteEmptyRows(){ 
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  var colNum = 0;// choose the column to check : 0=A, 1=B, 2=C etc... 
  var targetData = new Array();
  for(n=0;n<data.length;++n){
    if(data[n][colNum]!=''){ targetData.push(data[n])};// check the cell for "not empty" (does not detect formulas !!)
  }
  sh.getDataRange().clear();
  sh.getRange(1,1,targetData.length,targetData[0].length).setValues(targetData);
}
```

Comment: Apologize for the late response, didn't get the try the code until just now. I tried to run the code but nothing happens. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: As it is , the code deletes rows where cells in column A are empty.Tested and working. How did you try it ?

Comment: Apologize for the mess, but here's the code I'm using : var ordess = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Ordering"); //get name of the sheet to copy to var datas = ordess.getDataRange().getValues();
  var targetData = new Array();
  
  for (n=0;n<datas.length;++n) {
    if(datas[n][6]!=''){ targetData.push(datas[n])};
  }
  ordess.getDataRange().clear();
  ordess.getRange(1,1,targetData.length,targetData[0].length).setValues(targetData);  Since I was only looking for one specific column, I just used a number instead of creating a variable for it.

Comment: Are you sure about the number ? 6 is column G, is that what you want ? I copied/pasted your code and it works ... you must be doing something wrong but I don't know what. Sorry about that ;-).

Comment: I apologize! You're right. I was looking for column F. I assumed 6 was column F. So I'm off on how google sheet counts columns?  Again thanks for pointing it out. The code works great now.

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer, arrays count from 0 , A=0, B=1 etc.  I understand your confusion of course because A is definitely the first letter but 0  (in this case) can also be considered as the first number ;-)